# Cannot find android.app.ApplicationPackageManager

Tags: android, robolectric, android-package-managers

When compiling the following example from the [robolectric migration guide](http://robolectric.org/migrating/)

```
package com.jongla.soundmash.robolectric
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplicationPackageManager
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements
import android.app.ApplicationPackageManager

@Implements(value = ApplicationPackageManager.class, inheritImplementationMethods = true)
class MyCustomPackageManager extends ShadowApplicationPackageManager {
}
```

AndroidStudio is giving me `Unresolved reference: ApplicationPackageManager`. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this example to compile?  Do I need some additional `testCompile` package in gradle?

Comment: It looks like `ApplicationPackageManager` is not a public class. So clearly `import android.app.ApplicationPackageManager` can not be resolved

Comment: what's interesting is that i've included this in a package called android.app and even with that the example doesn't compile. i'm not sure why it's in the robolectric documentation if there's no way to actually do it...

Comment: Probably Robolectric was using some undocumented API

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking through Roboloectric source code, I ve spotted attribute `className` to specify class name instead. And it works like magic.

```
@Implements(className = "android.app.ApplicationPackageManager", inheritImplementationMethods = true)
public class MyCustomPackageManager extends ShadowApplicationPackageManager {
}
```

Migration document is clearly incorrect, when suggesting to use value as `ApplicationPackageManager` class is private and not visible for user code.